# RFID Reader coding

Tags: arduino, uart, rfid, processing

I Have got my ID-12 module active and putting out the RFID tags' details to Serial as

```
String valu = port.readStringUntil('\n');
```

... then I print that to serial. But I would like to use the information from the tag to determine changes in Processing environment. For example, change the background color of a box depending on which RFID tag is placed to the reader.

Does anyone know how I can do this or where I may find coding help?

#### Setup:

- [ID-12](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8419)
- [Arduino Duemilanova](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove)
- Serial, which I want to send to processing and use for a condition statement..

Comment: When you say *"serial"*, do you mean by UART/RS232 or over USB?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try http://processing.org/ for the programming language, there are some projects out there that use serial data to manipulate graphics and objects on screen.